# Compute elapsed time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am looking for some JavaScript simple samples to compute elapsed time. My scenario is, for a specific point of execution in JavaScript code, I want to record a start time. And at another specific point of execution in JavaScript code, I want to record an end time.

Then, I want to calculate the elapsed time in the form of: how many Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds are elapsed between end time and start time, for example: `0 Days, 2 Hours, 3 Minutes and 10 Seconds are elapsed`.

Any reference simple samples? :-)

Thanks in advance,

George

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>compute elapsed time in JavaScript</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function display_c (start) {
                window.start = parseFloat(start);
                var end = 0 // change this to stop the counter at a higher value
                var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
                if( window.start >= end ) {
                    mytime = setTimeout( 'display_ct()',refresh )
                } else {
                    alert("Time Over ");
                }
            }

            function display_ct () {
                // Calculate the number of days left
                var days = Math.floor(window.start / 86400);
                // After deducting the days calculate the number of hours left
                var hours = Math.floor((window.start - (days * 86400 ))/3600)
                // After days and hours , how many minutes are left
                var minutes = Math.floor((window.start - (days * 86400 ) - (hours *3600 ))/60)
                // Finally how many seconds left after removing days, hours and minutes.
                var secs = Math.floor((window.start - (days * 86400 ) - (hours *3600 ) - (minutes*60)))

                var x = window.start + "(" + days + " Days " + hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes and " + secs + " Secondes " + ")";

                document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
                window.start = window.start - 1;

                tt = display_c(window.start);
            }

            function stop() {
                clearTimeout(mytime);
            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="button" value="Start Timer" onclick="display_c(86501);"/> | <input type="button" value="End Timer" onclick="stop();"/>
        <span id='ct' style="background-color: #FFFF00"></span>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice answer.  How do you get the script to start when the page loads?

Comment: <body onload="display_c(86501);">  86501 is the time   Thank you again Ramiz.

Answer (score 112):

Try something like this ([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cckSj/5/))

```
// record start time
var startTime = new Date();

...

// later record end time
var endTime = new Date();

// time difference in ms
var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;

// strip the ms
timeDiff /= 1000;

// get seconds (Original had 'round' which incorrectly counts 0:28, 0:29, 1:30 ... 1:59, 1:0)
var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);

// remove seconds from the date
timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);

// get minutes
var minutes = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);

// remove minutes from the date
timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);

// get hours
var hours = Math.round(timeDiff % 24);

// remove hours from the date
timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 24);

// the rest of timeDiff is number of days
var days = timeDiff ;
```

Comment: The last line should be "var days = timeDiff;".. timeDays doesnt exist.

Comment: Shouldn't this be Math.floor()?

Comment: I.e. I am doing this: function ms2Time(ms) {
    var secs = ms / 1000;
    ms = Math.floor(ms % 1000);
    var minutes = secs / 60;
    secs = Math.floor(secs % 60);
    var hours = minutes / 60;
    minutes = Math.floor(minutes % 60);
    hours = Math.floor(hours % 24);
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + secs + "." + ms;  
}

Comment: @Dr.YSG That's really up to you. I prefer rounding the values than stripping the fraction part.

Comment: See fiddle and change it back to all rounding to see what's wrong with rounding except on calculating seconds. I'm not sure there is any purpose in rounding the mods (%) but I left your code.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was lazy to do it myself and search for one hour for this response... Yes it was possible to do it myself with this elapsed time ^^

Answer (score 22):

Try this...

```
function Test()
{
    var s1 = new StopWatch();

    s1.Start();        

    // Do something.

    s1.Stop();

    alert( s1.ElapsedMilliseconds );
} 

// Create a stopwatch "class." 
StopWatch = function()
{
    this.StartMilliseconds = 0;
    this.ElapsedMilliseconds = 0;
}  

StopWatch.prototype.Start = function()
{
    this.StartMilliseconds = new Date().getTime();
}

StopWatch.prototype.Stop = function()
{
    this.ElapsedMilliseconds = new Date().getTime() - this.StartMilliseconds;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Something like a "Stopwatch" object comes to my mind:

Usage:

```
var st = new Stopwatch();
st.start(); //Start the stopwatch
// As a test, I use the setTimeout function to delay st.stop();
setTimeout(function (){
            st.stop(); // Stop it 5 seconds later...
            alert(st.getSeconds());
            }, 5000);
```

Implementation:

```
function Stopwatch(){
  var startTime, endTime, instance = this;

  this.start = function (){
    startTime = new Date();
  };

  this.stop = function (){
    endTime = new Date();
  }

  this.clear = function (){
    startTime = null;
    endTime = null;
  }

  this.getSeconds = function(){
    if (!endTime){
    return 0;
    }
    return Math.round((endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000);
  }

  this.getMinutes = function(){
    return instance.getSeconds() / 60;
  }      
  this.getHours = function(){
    return instance.getSeconds() / 60 / 60;
  }    
  this.getDays = function(){
    return instance.getHours() / 24;
  }   
}
```

Comment: I think this thing is just great!

Answer (score 7):

```
var StopWatch = function (performance) {
    this.startTime = 0;
    this.stopTime = 0;
    this.running = false;
    this.performance = performance === false ? false : !!window.performance;
};

StopWatch.prototype.currentTime = function () {
    return this.performance ? window.performance.now() : new Date().getTime();
};

StopWatch.prototype.start = function () {
    this.startTime = this.currentTime();
    this.running = true;
};

StopWatch.prototype.stop = function () {
    this.stopTime = this.currentTime();
    this.running = false;
};

StopWatch.prototype.getElapsedMilliseconds = function () {
    if (this.running) {
        this.stopTime = this.currentTime();
    }

    return this.stopTime - this.startTime;
};

StopWatch.prototype.getElapsedSeconds = function () {
    return this.getElapsedMilliseconds() / 1000;
};

StopWatch.prototype.printElapsed = function (name) {
    var currentName = name || 'Elapsed:';

    console.log(currentName, '[' + this.getElapsedMilliseconds() + 'ms]', '[' + this.getElapsedSeconds() + 's]');
};
```

Benchmark

```
var stopwatch = new StopWatch();
stopwatch.start();

for (var index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
    stopwatch.printElapsed('Instance[' + index + ']');
}

stopwatch.stop();

stopwatch.printElapsed();
```

Output

```
Instance[0] [0ms] [0s]
Instance[1] [2.999999967869371ms] [0.002999999967869371s]
Instance[2] [2.999999967869371ms] [0.002999999967869371s]
/* ... */
Instance[99] [10.999999998603016ms] [0.010999999998603016s]
Elapsed: [10.999999998603016ms] [0.010999999998603016s]
```

[performance.now()](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now) is optional - just pass false into StopWatch constructor function.

Comment: The `performance.now()` link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I am using:

Milliseconds to a pretty format time string:

```
function ms2Time(ms) {
    var secs = ms / 1000;
    ms = Math.floor(ms % 1000);
    var minutes = secs / 60;
    secs = Math.floor(secs % 60);
    var hours = minutes / 60;
    minutes = Math.floor(minutes % 60);
    hours = Math.floor(hours % 24);
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + secs + "." + ms;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you can always grab the current time by

```
var currentTime = new Date();
```

Then you could check out this "pretty date" example at http://www.zachleat.com/Lib/jquery/humane.js

If that doesn't work for you, just google "javascript pretty date" and you'll find dozens of example scripts.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Gracefully hide from old browsers

// Javascript to compute elapsed time between "Start" and "Finish" button clicks
function timestamp_class(this_current_time, this_start_time, this_end_time, this_time_difference) { 
        this.this_current_time = this_current_time;
        this.this_start_time = this_start_time;
        this.this_end_time = this_end_time;
        this.this_time_difference = this_time_difference;
        this.GetCurrentTime = GetCurrentTime;
        this.StartTiming = StartTiming;
        this.EndTiming = EndTiming;
    }

    //Get current time from date timestamp
    function GetCurrentTime() {
    var my_current_timestamp;
        my_current_timestamp = new Date();      //stamp current date & time
        return my_current_timestamp.getTime();
        }

    //Stamp current time as start time and reset display textbox
    function StartTiming() {
        this.this_start_time = GetCurrentTime();    //stamp current time
        document.TimeDisplayForm.TimeDisplayBox.value = 0;  //init textbox display to zero
        }

    //Stamp current time as stop time, compute elapsed time difference and display in textbox
    function EndTiming() {
        this.this_end_time = GetCurrentTime();      //stamp current time
        this.this_time_difference = (this.this_end_time - this.this_start_time) / 1000; //compute elapsed time
        document.TimeDisplayForm.TimeDisplayBox.value = this.this_time_difference;  //set elapsed time in display box
        }

var time_object = new timestamp_class(0, 0, 0, 0);  //create new time object and initialize it

//-->
</script>

    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Start" onClick="time_object.StartTiming()"; name="StartButton">
    </form>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Finish" onClick="time_object.EndTiming()"; name="EndButton">
    </form>
    <form name="TimeDisplayForm">
    Elapsed time:
      <input type="text" name="TimeDisplayBox" size="6">
    seconds
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

write java program that enter elapsed time in seconds for any cycling event & the output format should be like (hour : minute : seconds ) for EX : elapsed time in 4150 seconds= 1:09:10