# Java script count up timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a working count down timer in java script and it count down from 120 seconds to 0, now I want to change it to becomes a COUNT UP timer,  try few thing still not work. could anyone help to change it to COUNT UP instead of COUNT DOWN.

Here is the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var m = 0;
var s = 120;
var timer_container = document.getElementById("survey-timer");
timer_container.innerHTML = s + "." + m;

function timer() {
    if (m<=0) {
        m = 9;
        s -= 1;
    }
    if(s>=0) {
        m -= 1;
        timer_container.innerHTML = s + "." + m;
        setTimeout(timer,100);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517597/plain-count-up-timer-in-javascript ?

Comment: Could you post what you did try, then we can see if it can be fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You want to count up from 120 or from 0.. below one just count up from 0..

```
   <script type="text/javascript" >
    var m=0
    var s=0
    var timer_container=document.getElementById("survey-timer");
    timer_container.innerHTML=s+"."+m;

    function timer(){
    if (m>=9){
        m=-1;
        s+=1;
    }
    if(s>=0){
        m+=1;
        timer_container.innerHTML=s+"."+m;
        setTimeout(timer,100);
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Here is working example from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvSnB/)

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would do this:

```js
var base = new Date();
var timer_container = document.getElementById("survey-timer");

timer();

function timer() {
  var now = new Date();
  // elapsed time in seconds
  var elapsed = (now - base) / 1000.0;
  timer_container.innerHTML = elapsed.toFixed(1);
  setTimeout(timer, 100);
}
```

```html
<div id="survey-timer">&nbsp;</div>
```

Because I think the technique used in the question and in rahul's answer might 'slip' if the timeout were delayed for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks, will try your version.