# How to implement timer in a web app built using play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework. I want to add a timer to a page which starts as soon as the user opens the page, which displays how long that particular page has been open.

But I have no idea how to implement the timer. Can anybody please tell how to do it.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this simply with Javascript without any server-side stuff: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517597/plain-count-up-timer-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

That's definitelly job for JavaScript not for framework.

There are available ready to use libraries, which you can use for that task, ie: [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or [TimeAgo](http://timeago.yarp.com/)