# How to change the color of a count up timer as time increases in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5517836/834616) with a simple JavaScript counter. How can I change the color of the counter, for e.g.:

- When it is above 10 seconds, its becomes red
- When it is above 20 seconds, it becomes orange.
- When it is above 30 seconds, it becomes blue.

Comment: Post your jQuery code (I assume you forgot to post it). Which you tried.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this.

```
if( timerCount > 10 && timerCount < 20 )
    timerDiv.style.color = 'Your color';
else if( timerCount > 20 && timerCount < 30 )
    timerDiv.style.color = 'Your color';
else
    timerDiv.style.color = 'Your color';
```

// timerCount is the variable being incremented
// timerDiv is the variable that is going to be the `div` being incremented.

**Edit suggested by @user3980820**

Comment: maybe you should edit your code because when it's above 20 it will only go on the first condition. 
`if(  totalSeconds > 10 && totalSeconds <20 )` 
and so I hope this will improve your code.

Comment: and also you should change the `elseif` statement to `else if( timercount > 20 && timercount < 30)