# Javascript Second Counter

Tags: javascript, counter

On my website, I am trying to count (and display) how many seconds (not minutes or hours) the user has been on my site. So, if they have been on it for 5 minutes, it will display 300, Not 5 minutes.
I am Very Unexperienced with JavaScript, So please help.

Comment: go to this link and check it out similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517597/plain-count-up-timer-in-javascript

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the `setInterval` function to run another function as often as you choose. For example:

```js
var seconds = 0;
var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

function incrementSeconds() {
    seconds += 1;
    el.innerText = "You have been here for " + seconds + " seconds.";
}

var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
```

```html
<div id='seconds-counter'> </div>
```

If you run this snippet, you'll see the counter working.

The `setInterval` function takes two parameters:

- the function you want to call
- the number of milliseconds between calls

Since you want to call increment the counter every second, you want to use 1000 milliseconds (1 second).

For more details, see the [MDN documentation for `setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Comment: This code can produce inaccurate values because it does not take into consideration possible delay of callback invocation.

Comment: Good point. I went for a really basic example, because of the "Very Inexperienced" comment, but I'll upvote the other answer.

Answer (score 9):

My answer is similar to the one above but I'll give it anyway. This will only work on a single page so hopefully your site already runs on AJAX.

```js
window.setInterval((function(){
   var start = Date.now();
   var textNode = document.createTextNode('0');
   document.getElementById('seconds').appendChild(textNode);
   return function() {
        textNode.data = Math.floor((Date.now()-start)/1000);
        };
   }()), 1000);
```

```html
You've been on this page for <span id=seconds></span> seconds.
```

Comment: This code is more accurate because it takes into consideration possible delay of callback invocation.