# jQuery time clock counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple jQuery Time counter just to count the user working time in my application displaying hours and minutes

**HTML:**

```
<body>
   <div><input type="text" class="time"/></div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
function startTimer(duration) {
   var timer = duration,hours, minutes;
   setInterval(function () {
        hours   = parseInt(timer / 3600, 10)
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);

        hours   = hours   < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

        $('input[type=text].time').val(hours + ":" + minutes);

        if (++timer < 0) {
           timer = 0;
        }

    }, 1);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
  var minutes = 0
  startTimer(minutes);
});
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/df773p9m/1856/

The problem is that at this time the counter does not reset when reach 60 minutes and continues to count, although the hours were updated.

**Notes:** I've set the interval to 1 ms in order to test the operation.

Comment: Fiddle does not work `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i've updated the fiddle

Comment: There are literally hundreds of articles on how to do this on the internet and several dozen on Stack Overflow. Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5517597/215552) for instance. Please read [ask]. Key phrase: "Search, and research".

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've just surfered mutch pages but can't find somenthing interesting, the link you provided isn't using jQuery and make only minutes and seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `%` after the division, otherwise  it'll continue

check this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df773p9m/1863/)

---

EDIT

Sean is right, I have fixed the code, the 24 should be in the % not the division also note that I'm multiplying duration by 60 to get the mins from the seconds

no need for the reset mins line anymore

```
function startTimer(duration) {
    var timer = duration*60,hours, minutes;
    setInterval(function () {
            hours   = parseInt((timer / 3600)%24, 10)
        minutes = parseInt((timer / 60)%60, 10);

        hours   = hours   < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

        $('input[type=text].time').val(hours + ":" + minutes);

        if (++timer < 0) {
            timer = 0;
        }
    }, 1);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var minutes = 1339;
    startTimer(minutes);
});
```

Comment: Perfect, it was what I needed

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/df773p9m/1859/

If your timer is in minutes, and it's counting up one minute at a time, you want to divide the total time by 60 to get hours.  Then you can get the remainder with the modulo operator `%` for the remaining minutes:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration,
    hours, 
    minutes;

    setInterval(function () {
        hours   = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        minutes = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        hours   = hours   < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

        $('#time').val(hours + ":" + minutes);

        // I have no idea what you're trying to do here, it appears this will never evaluate to true:
        if (++timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }


    }, 100); // this number should be changed to 60000 for it to be one minute (60,000 milliseconds = 1 minute)


}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var minutes = 0,
        display;
    startTimer(minutes, display);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()

> Remainder (%)
>
> The remainder operator returns the remainder left over when one
>   operand is divided by a second operand. It always takes the sign of
>   the dividend, not the divisor. It uses a built-in modulo function to
>   produce the result, which is the integer remainder of dividing var1 by
>   var2 — for example — var1 modulo var2. There is a proposal to get an
>   actual modulo operator in a future version of ECMAScript, the
>   difference being that the modulo operator result would take the sign
>   of the divisor, not the dividend.