# Easiest way to limit video upload length with HTML5 capture="capture"

Tags: html, video, limit, capture

I am building a site where users are able to capture pictures and video using their mobile phones. Everything works well in HTML5 and some javascript. But I would like to limit the max length of the videos **without the users having to capture the video first, and after receiving a warning that the video is too long.** This is the current video upload form I am using with success.

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" capture="capture">
```

Anyone with a solution/hack that would make the capture of the video automatically stop if it reaches more than 10 seconds?

As usual, thanks for the wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this too using MediaStream / MediaSource API's.

I ended up succumbing to using a [countdown timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517597/plain-count-up-timer-in-javascript) and stopping the recording upon the limit you want.

Quick ES6 + TypeScript example:

```
startRecording(): void {
    // ... record logic
    // ... countdown logic

    if (countdownTimer === maxSeconds) {
        this.stopRecording();
    }
}

stopRecording(): void {
    this.mediaRecorder.stop();
    this.isRecording = false;

    const blobPropertyBag: BlobPropertyBag = {
      type: 'video/webm'
    };
    this.fileBlob = new Blob(this.recordedBlobs, blobPropertyBag);

    this.stream.getTracks().forEach((track: MediaStreamTrack) => {
        track.stop();
    });
}
```