# Javascript elapsed time calculator

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am looking a pure javascript which calculates date for friendly view.

eg. 05-24-2012 3:10

--> 20 minutes ago

I have a php script and I'm looking javascript version.

```
<?php
$time = strtotime($_GET["d"]);
echo humanTiming($time);
function humanTiming($time)
{
 $time=time()-$time;
 $tokens=array(31536000=>'year',2592000=>'month',604800=>'week',86400=>'day',3600=>'hour',60=>'minute',1=>'second');
 foreach($tokens as $unit=>$text){if($time<$unit) continue;$numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');}
}
?>
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate. Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210701/compute-elapsed-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [JavaScript Relative Time Helpers](https://github.com/jherdman/javascript-relative-time-helpers)
- [JavaScript makes relative times compatible with caching](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1557-javascript-makes-relative-times-compatible-with-caching)
- [Relative Time in JavaScript](http://derekmd.com/2010/01/relative-time-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

well javascript implementation of what u have posted is available [here](http://psoug.org/snippet/Javascript-Calculate-time-difference-between-two-dates_116.htm) 
 also [this](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=196685)  may also be useful for you