# new Date() is inaccurate in PhoneGap - better time solution?

Tags: javascript, date, cordova, time

I'm trying to count the number of seconds my app has been paused, and every second during a timer, I'm capturing `new Date()`.

I have an 'onResume' listener that fires when the app opens, but `(new Date() - oldDate)` returns numbers like `96`, even if the app has been closed for 5 seconds.

Before I go create a javascript bridge to get the time in android and iOS, is there something that will do this for me already? I need time accurate to portions of a second, and `new Date` doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: see if this function can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1210749/982924

Comment: @RASG this is an answer, not a comment, and it's a wrong one at that. "Date" is fundamentally inaccurate, it looks like. I'm creating native bridges now to confirm my hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a native bridge and get the time from Android proper. This is the only way to get an accurate time (in the version of android most recent when the question was posted).