# I want my Javascript to expire in 30 days

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some code which can check whether 30 days have passed, and if so the script will stop working; if not, it calls the `start()` function.

I only need to do it in Javascript.

```
var date = 11;
var month = 10;
var year = 2012;

function Checkday() {
    if ( // check 30 days ) {
        start();
    } else {
        stop();
    };
};
```

I'm also wondering whether there is a way to add PHP code in a JS file. I know this is a stupid question but I'm just curious.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited:**

We will be selling the JS file so we will be setting the date in the JS file. So we want it to check the expiry time and stop functioning.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @MarcB. Expire javascript, Ohh, people have imagination now days...

Comment: @gdoron: they'll probably sell one copy...

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210701/compute-elapsed-time-in-javascript

Comment: yes its for selling and will be setting date in js file. no need for cookie and all

Comment: When you sell the JS file...the person will have complete access to it. Even if your idea wasn't riddled with flaws: they could just remove that piece of the code that makes it stop working.

Comment: yes but every one cant do it. its 50-50. all cant change setting and we have nice js packer

Comment: @MarcB. Doesn't know js but want to sell js. Funny how things work...

Comment: @deerox You don't sell things with a 50-50 chance of working... do you?

Comment: @deerox: there is no js packer that can't be bypassed. just because you can't doesn't mean no one else can either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you..

```
var date = 11;
var month = 10;
var year = 2012

function Checkday() {
    if ( !isExpired() ) {
        start();
        } else {
        stop();
    };
};

function isExpired() {

    var current = new Date(); 
    current = current.getTime(); 

    var dateToCheck = new Date(); 
    dateToCheck.setFullYear(year); 
    dateToCheck.setMonth(month); 
    dateToCheck.setDate(date + 30) 
    var checkdate = dateToCheck.getTime();

    return checkdate < current
}
```

Comment: Problem is taking computer time. How to make it gmtime

Comment: this link will help you, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp  it has all the functions available in date

Answer (score 4):

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YBHtC/2/) for you.

```
var date = 10;
var month = 10;
var year = 2012;

var expires = new Date(year, month, date);
function checkDate() {
    var d = new Date();
    return(d>expires);
}
```

Give your js file the ending .php and put `header('content-type: application/x-javascript');` at the beginning of it. Now you can `<?php echo $variables; ?>` inside of it. This workouround must not work in ie*.

Nevertheless: if you're selling the js and want to stop this function when a given timepoint is reached: This is not solvable via javascript! Anybody could edit a javascript file - like the date, month, year params. Except you hava a js packer, which - IMHO - is not safe enough.

Comment: You can do: `new Date(year, month, date);`... probably better.

Answer (score 2):

Silly question, but what is to stop the people you are selling this JavaScript file to from opening it up themselves and changing the date? Are you selling this file to them so they can use it in their website? I have to imagine that they will be smart enough to think of that.

Also, php is a server-side language while JavaScript is a client-side language, so putting php in the JS file directly wouldn't do you much good. Really your best bet is to save the dateinfo in a cookie and check it before calling the function.

Comment: we have nice packer and it will be added on addon on firefox.

Comment: i know php is server side language but as answer above i have to end up link with .php check above