# How to count time elapsed from the moment a popup appeared till it was clicked in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [compute elapsed time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210701/compute-elapsed-time-in-javascript)

I am trying to construct a lexical decision task for my psychology project.

The task is in javascript: a popup with a word appears and a user clicks yes or no depending on whether the word is grammatical.

I need to count the time between the appearance of the popup and the user click. Could you tell em what needs to be done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210701/compute-elapsed-time-in-javascript second answer =)

Answer (score 3):

when the pop-up appears you could store the current time retrieved with this statement:

```
var createDate = new Date().getTime();
```

Then when the user click on Yes or No you retrieve the new date and compute the difference with the previous timestamp:

```
var delay = new Date().getTime() - createDate;
```